# What kind of function is this?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory, holder-spaces

Let $0<\lambda\le1$ and consider 
$$
\Theta:(\Bbb R[X]_0,||\cdot||_{\lambda})\longrightarrow(\mathcal C^{\lambda}[0,1],||\cdot||_{\lambda})
$$
defined as 
$$
\Theta(p):=\sup_{u\le\cdot}p(u)
$$
(in the sense that the polynomial $p$ is sent by $\Theta$ to the function $t\mapsto\sup_{u\le t}p(u)$)
where  $\Bbb R[X]_0$ denotes the space of one variable polynomials with real coefficients which vanish at $0$, $\mathcal C^{\lambda}[0,1]$ is the space of $\lambda-$ Holder continuous functions $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R$ and $||\cdot||_{\lambda}$ denotes the usual $\lambda-$Holder norm.

What kind of function is $\Theta$? What property has? Does $\Theta$ belong to a family of functions which has a name and for which a theory is developed somewhere? Can someone suggest me some reference?

I guess we are near Functional Analysis field, but, beyond this, only fog.

Many thanks

Comment: Typo? You have "$\sup_{u\leq \cdot}$"

Comment: What is $X$? This reads like the "cumulative maximum".

Comment: @DanielWainfleet & grew: hi guys, I've just edited to get the post clearer.